# How to have a hierarchy of custom post types and use two of them in the permalink?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, hierarchical

#### General Setup

I'm working on a setup to create a documentary/wiki site for a company. The site should have three different levels of hierarchy and one type of content at the lower end:

- level 1: `area` (high level structure, e.g. 'internal stuff' or 'external projects')
- level 2: `topic` (main structure, e.g. 'controlling' or 'project xyz')
- level 3: `section` (groups the content, for a project this could be 'project management')
- level 4: `content` (custom post type that holds the content, basically like
  pages)

**Issue 1**

Ideally I have a custom post type for all four level. But is this even possible? Can I have a custom post type under another custom post type? I didn't find anything about this...

#### Permalinks

So the permalinks should be like this:

```
mysite.com/area/external-projects
```

Simply lists all topics in this area, so area is kind of a category for topic

```
mysite.com/topic/project-xyz
```

Lists all the sections and the content entries.

Link to section is not needed.

The link to content is tricky and the point where I need help:

```
mysite.com/topic/my-topic/content/this-is-my-content
```

**Issue 2**

So, the permalinks for the content should include the topic and the content. Is this even possible if the section (the hierarchy between them) is not in the permalink?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [custom hierarchical taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/) and use it for your custom post type.

Register the Taxonomy `area` for the post type `content` using the `init` action hook:

```
function wporg_register_taxonomy_area() {
   $labels = array(
     'name'              => _x( 'Areas', 'taxonomy general name' ),
     'singular_name'     => _x( 'Area', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
     'search_items'      => __( 'Search Areas' ),
     'all_items'         => __( 'All Areas' ),
     'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Area' ),
     'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Area:' ),
     'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Area' ),
     'update_item'       => __( 'Update Area' ),
     'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Area' ),
     'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Area Name' ),
     'menu_name'         => __( 'Area' ),
   );
   $args   = array(
     'hierarchical'      => true, // make it hierarchical (like categories)
     'labels'            => $labels,
     'show_ui'           => true,
     'show_admin_column' => true,
     'query_var'         => true,
     'rewrite'           => [ 'slug' => 'area' ],
   );
   register_taxonomy( 'area', [ 'content' ], $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wporg_register_taxonomy_area' );
```

Register custom post type `content` using the `init` action hook:

```
function my_custom_content_item() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Content', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Content', 'post type singular name' ),
        'menu_name'          => 'Content'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'public'        => true,
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'taxonomies'    => array( 'area' ),
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'content', $args );

} 
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_content_item' );
```

Adds the registered taxonomy `area` to object type `content`.

```
function attach_area_to_content() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'area', 'content' );
}
add_action('init','attach_area_to_content');
```